# how to make browser to fetch script files only when a certain conditons are true, in html code?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML coding, there is a media attribute for link tag, which tells the browser to fetch the style-sheet only when that media condition is true. Is there any similar attribute for script tag? if the answer is no,then, is there any other way to tell the browser to fetch script files only when the device width is small.

In order to make this clear, somehow i need to tell the browser "*only request this script file when viewport width is below 560px*". But don't know how to do?

Comment: Better when you load your application on a device, first check the **vw** and then load script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you..

```js
var url = "https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.js";
$.getScript(url, function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    $(".block")
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 180, 180)"
      }, 1000)
      .delay(500)
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "olive"
      }, 1000)
      .delay(500)
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "#00f"
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Source : [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: Instead of getting script file from the server, you can give the local add of the script file. Put this in a if condition and you achieve what you want.